# Return conditional formatting on html with external .css file

Tags: html, css

I have a html file that asks user for information, by inputting information into a form box (i.e name, email address, age). When these fields are blank, they should be highlighted with a red border.

If I put the following css styling code in the html page, the highlighting works. However, if I store it in an external css page, the highlighting does not work.

The below works, but the second set doesn't work when it is in the external css file.

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <style>
        input:invalid {
            border: 2px dashed red;
        }

        input:valid {
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

```css
<style>
    input:invalid {
        border: 2px dashed red;
    }

    input:valid {
        border: 2px solid black;
    }
</style>
```

How would I go about getting the styling to work from the css file, or is it even possible?

Comment: Either you are changing the CSS when you put it in the external file, or you are loading the external file incorrectly. The problem is not with the working code you've shown us.

Comment: There may be `Specificity` issues

Comment: Share HTML snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach could be to add classes like `.valid` and `.invalid` to the input fields on posting to signify the validity of the fields. This will also circumvent any specificity issues you might be having with your original approach.

```css
input.invalid {
    border: 2px dashed red;
}

input.valid {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<input class="invalid" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Invalid" />
<input class="valid" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Valid" />
```